# Enviar datos de audio (cliente) con Websocket para un Audio Streaming

Tags: php, javascript, socket, stream

Tengo el siguiente código que hace el envío de vídeo:

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getUserMedia = ( 
            navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    if (navigator.getUserMedia){//si es compatible  

        navigator.getUserMedia ({audio: true, video:true},  //video:false (para solo audio)
            function(vid) {
                bandera = 1;
                document.querySelector('video').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(vid);
            },function(err) {
                console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
            }
        );

    }else{
        console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
    }

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
        return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/100 );
        };
    })();

    function dFrame(ctx,video,canvas){
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',0.2);
        if(bandera!=0) 
            send(dataURL);//aca se envia con el socket  

        requestAnimFrame(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){dFrame(ctx,video,canvas);},200)
        });
    }

    window.addEventListener('load',init);//inicia cuando carga la pagina
    function init(){
        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        dFrame(ctx,video,canvas);
    }
```

Quiero adaptar el código para que sólo sea de audio. Ya que no tengo la mínima idea de cómo debe capturarse para enviarlo en el socket, y también como debe recibirse en los otros clientes y poner en reproducción con la etiqueta  u otro elemento de ser el caso.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: conforme lo que veo, siento que no has revisado el código y tampoco has hecho algún intento porque en los comentarios del mismo código dice: //video:false (para solo audio)

Comment: Ese comentario lo agregué yo. Y bueno, de hecho intente cambiado la etiqueta de vídeo por audio, pero al tratar con la función init(), no encontré una forma de tomar el audio en reproducción. En el ejemplo, se puede ver como se renderiza en la imágen de <video> hacia el <canvas>, y del <canvas> es enviado con el socket. Mi duda seria como tratar con el audio, para enviarlo.